# add properties to a list rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Property has many lists. List has many properties. Users can add properties to a list , here user must be owner of those properties which he want to add.

Here is my code:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propertyships
  has_many :properties, :through => :propertyships
end

class Propertyship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propertyships
  has_many :lists, :through => :propertyships
end
```

in view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@list, url: add_property_list_path,  :method => :put) do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:property_ids, @user_all_properties, :id, :street_address) %>
   <%= f.submit "Add Property" %>
<% end %>
```

in routes:

```
  resources :lists do
    member do
      put 'add_property'
    end
  end
```

in controller:

```
  def add_property
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @list.update_attributes(list_params)
  end
  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :user_id, property_ids: [])
  end
```

when I checked properties and I click "Add property" button as other user , its add checked properties but remove old properties that I have in that particular list.  what a I doing wrong??

Comment: Nothing, but it's the way that association method works.  If you want to add to the existing list you need to use `<<` but surely your collection check boxes already has the existing ones preselected?

Comment: yes, checkboxes preselected but not all of them . because current user is not  owner of all properties.

Comment: @j-dexx how can i grab those properties that checked by current user ??

Comment: The ids will be in your `list_params`

Comment: You could have hidden fields for the ones you want to always be selected but not shown to the user.

Comment: @j-dexx i tried but getting this:
`=>@list.property_ids << list_params[:property_ids]`
`=> [5, 15, ["15", "6", "5", ""]]`